# How to save MemoryAnalyzerTool (MAT) Object Query Language (OQL) result to file?

Tags: eclipse-memory-analyzer

The result of my query is too large for the table (100k elements). I want to save it to a file so I can apply text processing like sort, uniq and awk to do interesting aggregates like group.

I tried saving it to a txt file, but the result looks like:

```
myClass
---------------------------------------------
String1
String2
.
.
.
String20
Total: 20 of 750,129 entries; 750,109 more
--------------------------------------------
```

How can I save the entire result to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After executing `OQL` query, select sigma row.

i.e.:

```
Total: 16 of 2,584 entries; 2568
```

[image]

Then press icon of "Export" on the top, and choose "Export to CSV..."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed to save as csv. It saves all rows. If you save as txt, for some reason it saves only the first 20 rows.